# Does Cufon work in FBML static pages?

Tags: javascript, fbml, fbjs, cufon

Just as the title says, does Cufon work in FBML static pages?

If not, what works to replace the fonts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does't work on FBML. If you want cufon to work, you have to do the iFrame method. I'm not sure if @font-face works on FMBL though.